# Magento 1.4.2 - Set Address Fields During Registration

Tags: magento

I am trying to populate address fields during registration, using data from another system. In my observer, I am able to use

```
$customer = $observer->getCustomer();
$customer->setFirstname($value);
$customer->setLastname($value);
```

and the information is saved in the database, but

```
$customer->setStreet($value);
$customer->setPostcode($value);
$customer->setTelephone($value);
```

do not. How would I set address fields?
Thanks!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337929/how-to-add-the-address-fields-in-the-customer-registration-form/9545070#9545070

Answer (score 1):

Addresses are not stored in the `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` object. You should instead do something like:

```
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$address->setStreet(...);
...
$customer->addAddress($address);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried your code, and added `Mage::log($address);` before `$customer->addAddress($address);`. I am getting my entire address in the log, but it's still not saving to the database.

Comment: Did you remember to do a $customer->save() ?

Answer (score 0):

I found some good posts:
this was easier for me:-)
http://www.pauldonnellydesigns.com/blog/magento-display-address-fields-in-create-an-account/
and longer post: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/11110/

It's working, I checked.

I need show fields form address in orders, controller: /checkout/onepage on the page with form login and register (I want add fields personal and address in step register)

Do someone saw code to create for this functionality?