# how to add the address fields in the customer registration form?

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.6. And I want to display the address fields on the customer registration form.
I remove the following lines from the register.phtml but it did not work.

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

IF you are using magento 1.6 or above, and simply commenting following in customers/form/register.phtml

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

is not working then possibly you have active the persistent cart. In that case you need to comment the same lines in persistent/customer/form/register.phtml and it will work for you.
Don't forget to comment the same above code from the script on the end of the same page, which is for Region Updater.

Comment: Confirmed still working in 1.7.0.2, and the function itself still doesn't seem to be implemented, so you're gonna have to comment the if/else-clause out like Malik wrote.

Comment: This is not a missing function but an example of Magentos "magic getters" to access arbitrary attributes. As soon as any code calls `setShowAddressFields(true)`, the getter returns true. This call can even be done via layout XML, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28551919/664108

Answer (score 2):

go to : app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml

```
<customer_account_create>
  <reference name="customer_form_register">
    <action method="setShowAddressFields">
      <param>true</param>
    </action>
  </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Register.phtml app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `show_address_fields` attribute is intended to be set in your theme via layout XML.

In your theme's `local.xml`, add the following lines (before `</layout>`):

```
<customer_account_create>
  <reference name="customer_form_register">
    <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>1</value></action>
  </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

If you don't have a customized theme but a bought one, you should create a child theme for customizations like this.

### Example

For the Ultimo theme, the theme resides in `app/design/frontend/ultimo/default` (Ultimo is the "package", "default" the theme).

You should then create the directory `app/design/frontend/ultimo/yourname/layout` and add a file `local.xml` there:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
      <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>1</value></action>
    </reference>
  </customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

Then configure the custom theme:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

Refer this [DOC](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/contacts/add_fields_to_contact_form)

Try

```
<input name="x" id="x" title="<?php echo $this->__('x') ?>" value="" type="text"/>
```